# Find the subgroups that are conjugates of H in G and find order of quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\alpha = (2 3 5 4)$ and $\beta = (1 2 3 4 5)$, $H = \langle\alpha\rangle$ and $K = \langle\beta\rangle$. Let $G = N_{S_5}K = HK$. Find the subgroups that are conjugates of $H$ in $G$ and find the order of quotient group $G/K$.

For the first question, I know that the number of conjugates of H is the index of the normalizer of $H$ in $G$ is $|G|/|N_GH| = 20/4 = 5$. However, I'm not sure how to find these subgroup, I know that $gHg^{-1} = H_1, g \in G$.

For the 2nd question, I'm not sure how to begin.

I would really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I mean any subgroup conjugates to H, I denoted it as H1. Just edited the question

Comment: If $H$ is self-normalizing, which is what you claim, then any element of $G$ that is not in $H$ will give you a conjugate of $H$, and elements of distinct cosets of $H$ in $G$ will give you distinct conjugates. As to the order of $G/K$, you have $G=HK$, so $G/K= HK/K\cong H/H\cap K$, so all you need to do is find out $H\cap K$ to get the size.

Comment: you mean left or right cosets of H in G?

Comment: Either.${}{}{}{}$